# iPad launch images in Xcode 5 accept just retina or non retina but not both

Tags: ipad, ios7, xcode5, retina-display

I am setting all the new launch images needed in the new Xcode, but I'm having a very strange problem... when I put the Portrait Non-Retina (768x1024) image there are no problems... but then when I go to put the Portrait Retina (1536x2048) image, this last one appears with no problems but the Non-Retina one disappears and it appears an error saying: no image with correct dimensions found.... and the same thing happens also for the two landscape images...
I'm adding 2 images so you better understand the problem....

Here I have the 2 Non-Retina setted

[image]

and when I set the 2 Retina the Non-Retina disappears...

[image]

anyone is facing the same problem? is there a solution to that?
Thanks for any help.
Massy

Comment: In iOS6 and lower you should not include the space for the status bar in your launchimage.

Comment: I followed the measures on Xcode... do you mean that Portrait Non-Retina shouldn't be 768x1024 as stated in Xcode?

Comment: When using assets library you will even be warned by about the non retina one

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I struggled with this also, but I've found this is solved when you have a non-retina image named image.png and its retina counterpart is named image@2x.png.
So to fix yours you'll need to name the first
"Default-Portrait-1024~ipad" and the second "Default-Portrait-1024@2x~ipad". The part preceding the "@2x~ipad" needs to be the same for it to recognize them both. It's dumb and can make the naming confusing, but that's how it works for now. I'm not sure if this functionality is intentional, since it doesn't seem to work this way for any of the icon images...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot! That worked like a charm! Peace... Massy

Comment: After struggling with trying to get this working I realized that the ~ipad modifier is case-sensitive. I had ~iPad in my filenames and I was seeing the same behavior. After changing them to ~ipad, they were all accepted. My theory is that Apple wants only one record in the info.plist file for UILaunchImages~ipad for each orientation, so its looking for the identical name with a valid @2x~ipad modifier at the end of the filename and cannot find it. The editor doesn't let you add the retina image if you selected the non-retina image already because it only allows one entry per orientation.

Comment: Indeed, the capitalization of the P in ipad causes problems. Thanks!

Comment: This answer has made my life much easier!

Comment: This is an absolutely ridiculous way for Apple to do this, and obscure. Why am I wasting a considerable amount of my time on something so trivial? There needs to be a better solution.

Comment: For the iphone 4-inch settings I needed a file with a 568h@2x-iphone suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching what `Xcode 5` adds to the `plist` to remove my warnings.

[image: info.plist]

Answer (score 0):

maybe "YourApp-info.plist" file has problem. check it. i have same problem and i found problem in "YourApp-info.plist" file. in my problem that file deleted before and new location of file was incorrect.